# Find joint density of $X$ and $\exp(-X)$

Tags: probability

$X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable in $[-a,a]$.

Find joint density of $X$ and $\exp(-X)$.

Addition: This is in context to the first undergraduate course in probability

I tried to solve it using Y = exp(-X). Then solving for:
P(X=x,Y=y) = P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x) gives the following result, which I am doubtful about:
P(X=x,Y=y) = f(x) when y = exp(-x) and zero otherwise.

Also, as pointed out in an answer that the Lebesgue measure is actually zero, so there will not exist a density distribution is what I could think of after seeing the distribution I got which is analytically highly discrete.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Hi,

I am sorry, but this is in context to the first undergraduate course in probability.

Comment: I upvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks! for familiarizing me with the usage of this awesome site!!

Comment: "_Also, as pointed out in an answer that the Lebesgue measure is actually zero, so there will not exist a density distribution is what I could think of after seeing the distribution I got which is analytically highly discrete._" I don't understand this sentence. Would you like to picture the common cdf?

Answer (score 2):

The pair $\left(X,e^{-X}\right)$ does not have a common density because their common distribution is concentrated on the set

$$\{(x,y)\mid y=e^{-x}, \ -a\le x\le a\}$$

of $0$ Lebesgue measure. There is neither density nor pmf. ([The lebesgue measure and the measure belonging to the common distribution of $\left(X,e^{-X}\right)$ are singular.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem))